# C Programming File opens but cant store with another file's data

Tags: c, file

Hello Guys I am a beginner of C programming.I want to practice with small project.The program will scan lines and whenever found the desired line change it and store another file.The program looks like good but the problem is that updated file is openning but cant store the data.Code is below Please help me to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME_SIZE 1024
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define FIELD_COUNT 7

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    FILE *newfile;
    
    char filename[FILENAME_SIZE];
    printf("File:");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    file=fopen(filename,"r");
    
    newfile=fopen("updatedReferences.txt","w");
    char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        char *fields[FIELD_COUNT];
        char *space = strtok(line, ",");
        int field_index = 0;
        while (space) {
        fields[field_index++] = space;
        space = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        char *MLA_surname = fields[0];
        while (*MLA_surname == ' ') {
            MLA_surname++;
        }
        int MLA_surnameLength = strlen(MLA_surname);
        while (MLA_surnameLength > 0 && MLA_surname[MLA_surnameLength - 1] == ' ') {
            MLA_surnameLength--;
        }
        MLA_surname[MLA_surnameLength] = '\0';

        char *MLA_names = fields[1];
        while (*MLA_names == ' ') {
          MLA_names++;
        }
        int MLA_namesLength = strlen(MLA_names);
        while (MLA_namesLength > 0 && MLA_names[MLA_namesLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_namesLength--;
        }
        MLA_names[MLA_namesLength] = '\0';
        
        char *MLA_title = fields[2];
        while (*MLA_title == ' ') {
          MLA_title++;
        }
        int MLA_titleLength = strlen(MLA_title);
        while (MLA_titleLength > 0 && MLA_title[MLA_titleLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_titleLength--;
        }
        MLA_title[MLA_titleLength] = '\0';
        
        char *MLA_journal = fields[3];
        while (*MLA_journal == ' ') {
          MLA_journal++;
        }
        int MLA_journalLength = strlen(MLA_journal);
        while (MLA_journalLength > 0 && MLA_journal[MLA_journalLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_journalLength--;
        }
        MLA_journal[MLA_journalLength] = '\0';
        
        char *MLA_issue_number = fields[4];
        while (*MLA_issue_number == ' ') {
          MLA_issue_number++;
        }
        int MLA_issue_numberLength = strlen(MLA_issue_number);
        while (MLA_issue_numberLength > 0 && MLA_issue_number[MLA_issue_numberLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_issue_numberLength--;
        }
        MLA_issue_number[MLA_issue_numberLength] = '\0';
        
        char *MLA_year = fields[5];
        while (*MLA_year == ' ') {
          MLA_year++;
        }
        int MLA_yearLength = strlen(MLA_year);
        while (MLA_yearLength > 0 && MLA_year[MLA_yearLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_yearLength--;
        }
        MLA_year[MLA_yearLength] = '\0';
        
        char *MLA_pages = fields[6];
        while (*MLA_pages == ' ') {
          MLA_pages++;
        }
        int MLA_pagesLength = strlen(MLA_pages);
        while (MLA_pagesLength > 0 && MLA_pages[MLA_pagesLength - 1] == ' ') {
          MLA_pagesLength--;
        }
        MLA_pages[MLA_pagesLength] = '\0';
        
        char reference[BUFFER_SIZE];
        snprintf(reference, BUFFER_SIZE, "%s, %c. (%s). %s. %s", MLA_surname, MLA_names[0], MLA_year, MLA_title, MLA_journal);
        if (MLA_issue_numberLength > 0) {
          strncat(reference, " ", BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(reference) - 1);
          strncat(reference, MLA_issue_number, BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(reference) - 1);
        }
        strncat(reference, ", ", BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(reference) - 1);
        strncat(reference, MLA_pages, BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(reference) - 1);
        strncat(reference, ".", BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(reference) - 1);
        
        fprintf(newfile, "%s\n", reference);
    }
    fclose(newfile);
}
```

Comment: First, always check for return and error codes, and learn to use a debugger. Second, always reduce to a minimal code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read a specific file format. I don't have an example of that kind of file, so I can't test the program to read that, but I can say that, when trying to read an arbitrary file, it crashes almost immediately. That is because (at least with the file that I tried to read, the program's own source file) the `fields` array is not initialized because the first internal loop doesn't find the characters it is looking for.

Without more information I can't help you any more, but I strongly suggest that you learn how to use a debugger (I know it may sound scary, but in cases like this it's really useful), you add error checking in your code (look into `errno` and read the docs of the various functions), and learn to use `assert`.